# CSS flex - is it possible to vertically align <h1> and <p> next to an <img> without using containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

A very common element containing an image, title and text is

```
<div class="mediaelement">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
<h1>The title. Unknown length.</h1>
<p>And the description. Which could also span multiple lines.</p>
</div>
```

Now display: flex appears to be a very flexible way to center and display items. E.g with the order property I could move the title before the image without touching dom.

But is it possible to align both the h1 and p vertically to the image without putting the into another container? Using only css?

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwwpQ.jpg

[image: example]

If i put them into a container, I cannot move the h1 before the image with the flex order value.

Comment: Is using `absolute;` positioning allowed?

Comment: The point is the the height of elements is unknown. 

Using top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); doesn't work since the <h1> and the <p> should "work together"

Comment: In the screenshot I took, I got one method working but it was using display: table; & table-cell & vertical-align

But I feel that is kind of hacky method.

Comment: I've made some progress:

![http://i.imgur.com/QcR9Dkw.png](http://i.imgur.com/QcR9Dkw.png)

The .mediaelement has to have a set height. Some problems still with the width of the text elements.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is....**with one proviso**. You need to know the height of the parent element.

Basically, you need column layout with wrapping. In order for the parent to know *when* to wrap you **must** have a limited height...or it just won't wrap.

```css
.mediaelement {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mediaelement">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <h1>The title. Unknown length.</h1>
  <p>And the description. Which could also span multiple lines.</p>
</div>
```

Once `display:contents` gains support this kind of fiddling about will become unnecessary as it will be possible to wrap and unwrap elements from their containers as required.

Comment: Thanks. The widths of h1 ja p are a problem.

They are the 100% width of the parent when they should take the width of the img into account. 

one way to fix it is with calc. Example:
http://i.imgur.com/QcR9Dkw.png

Comment: @Paulie_D - Hey, 2+ years later here, but I'm curious why you say you wouldn't encourage anyone to use this method?  Were you referring to your answer or Jaska's comment?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's Paulie_D's answer expanded to show the smaller issue with the widths of h1 and p. But this is already good enough solution for some cases.

```css
.mediaelement {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mediaelement">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" style="
    padding-right: 10px;
">
  <h1 style="
    width: calc(100% - 210px);
    margin: 0;
">The title. Unknown length. Could be 2 lines</h1>
  <p style="
    width: calc(100% - 210px);
    margin: 0;
">And the description. Which could also span multiple lines.And the description. Which could also span multiple lines.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question :)

With CSS grid, this is easier to solve.

https://codepen.io/Jaska/pen/VQGqWK

```
.mediaelement {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

img {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}
h1 {
  grid-row: 2
}
p {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

So the img fills all the rows 1-4 so the h1 and p have to go to the second column. And I added h1 to start from row 2 and p to start from row 3 so there remains 2 equal height rows above and under the content.